# Building and linking to a executable

Tags: executable, blender, cmake

I'm interested in creating a system wide executable or link for the latest version of Blender  which I built from source using this [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux). Long story short, I got it built and it appears to run correctly (I haven't thoroughly tested it but everything seems in order). However it did not add the Blender binary system wide (if that's the correct terminology).
I went through the process of typing:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Basically, I want to be able to pop open a terminal and type 'blender' to get it to run, or simply create a desktop icon and open it that way. I tried simply right-clicking the generated binary and using the 'Make Link' option, but the link crashes when clicked outside of the build directory.

Lastly, I realize there's a perfectly good distribution of Blender in the software center, but I am weird and I wanted to build it from source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recall, Blender's make install generally does not actually put itself in system executable directories.

My suggestion would be to use the `.local` folder in your home directory (or create it if it isn't there)

- `mkdir -p ~/.local/opt`
- copy the blender source code into that directory, giving you something like `~/.local/opt/blender`
- `mkdir -p ~/.local/bin`: create a `bin` directory where you can put your own executable files
- Edit your `.bashrc` file: `gedit ~/.bashrc`
  at the end of that file, put this line: `export PATH=${HOME}/.local/bin:${PATH}`
  This will prepend `~/.local/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.
- For this edit to take effect, you will need to do `source ~/.bashrc` for any shell that is already running.  Any new terminal that you start after saving the edited file will have the new PATH already.  If you want to be able to run blender from the gui using `Alt-F2` you will need to restart (or perhaps just log out and log in again, not sure).  You can check to see if this folder is on your path by typing `echo ${PATH}`, and ensuring that `/home/youruser/.local/bin` is at the beginning
- symbolic link the blender executable that you built into this bin directory:  `ln -s ~/.local/opt/blender/<blender executable> ~/.local/bin/blender`

Now, when you type `blender` at the command line, the program should run.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent walkthrough. Have you worked on Blender's source code before by any chance? =D

Comment: as in developed? not really.  I seem to remember having tried to build it from source once, though